# using a portable int

Tags: c

gcc c99 MS2005/2008

I have started program that will be compiled on linux/windows.

The program will be compiled on linux using gcc 4.4.1 c99. And on windows the compiler will be either MS 2005/2008. And this I cannot change.

I am using SCons to create the build files. However, the reason I choose c99 as I can use the stdint.h so my integers would be compatible between different architectures i.e. x86_32 and 64 bit. using int32_t so it will compile without any problem on both 32 and 64 bit machines.

However, I have just discovered that c99 isn't used for ms compilers. Only c89. However, c89 doesn't have the stdint.t.

I am wondering what is the best way to make the integer portable among different compilers running on either 32 or 64.

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Note that MSVC does not support a lot of the C99 features.  For portability between Linux and Windows, you would be better off using C89.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually trying to directly map a binary format "from the wire", then you probably don't really need a fixed-width type at all.

By way of example, if you're using `int32_t` just because you need an integer than can store all values in the range `-2147483647` to `2147483647`, then a simple `long` is perfectly portable for that application - it is guaranteed to be at least that wide.

People seem to be inordinately keen on exact-width types.